# Altium 21.1.1 - Disable component clearance

Tags: pcb-design, altium, clearance

I'm royally confused!

I have Altium 20.x.x on one PC. I do a PCB design on this PC and I have no issues. I port that same project to Altium 21.1.1 and suddenly I have major clearance issues when I go to design the PCB. Certain components can be placed next to each other while others have an incredibly large clearance requirement.

I've ported my settings from one Altium to the other, and vice versac, and it doesn't make a difference. I've played with all sorts of settings in the preferences and nothing has changed this. I've created a constraints file and set the horizontal clearance to zero. I've attached a picture of an example. I then just started a new project in Altium 21.1.1 and used different components but when I go to design the PCB layout I have the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the exact error? Are you using rooms?

Comment: Export the design rules from AD20, and AD21, and compare with a text editor.  Also, look for design rules that have not been set in AD21.  I seem to recall that if certain rules are not defined, then some defaults are assumed that may be too conservative.  I would also look for primitives on disabled layers that are causing the warnings (like a courtyard, bottom overlay, or other mechanical layers).  Good luck!

Comment: BTW, as of this date, IMHO avoid AD21 as it has a whole host of problems.

Comment: Alright... well maybe I just need to roll back to AD20. I've had a "host of other issues" as you suggested with just getting to this point. None of these issues existed in 20.x.x. Who knows what else is waiting for me around the corner once I figure this issue out.

Comment: Silk screen and "pin-1" circles on mechanical layers were my culprits in AD21.

Comment: Are you sure it's a component clearance problem and not a room definition problem? Please post a screenshot of the actual DRC errors.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I ended up having to get the PCB out today and just rolled my Altium Version back. Using 20.2.7 I do not have any of the issues I've run into previously. And no, I just assumed it was a clearance issue. I don't really use rooms all that much.